# Finite field extension

Tags: finite-fields, extension

Suppose $$f_a=x^p-x-\left [\prod_{j=1}^{a-1} \alpha_j\right]^{p-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{a-1})[x]$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{a-1}) $, where $\alpha_i$ is a root of $f_i$ with $i<a$. And suppose $\alpha_a$ is a root of $f_a$. How do I prove that $$\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_a)=\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_a)?$$

It's easy to see that $$\left [\prod_{j=1}^{a-1} \alpha_j\right]^{p-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_a),$$ how do we conclude that $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_a)$ ?

Comment: Have you made all necessary assumptions on the $\alpha_i$? This seems false for $p=2,\alpha =1$.

Comment: For all $c \in \mathbf F_p^\times$ the polynomial $x^p - x - c$ is irreducible over $\mathbf F_p$, so is your irreducibility "hypothesis" exactly what you mean to say: irreducibility over $\mathbf F_p$?

Comment: $\alpha=1$ is not a root of $x^2-x-1$. And each $f_i$ is irreducible, i just put it as an assumption, because im not going to prove it here.

Comment: [Crossposted at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260697/11619)